# Sending HTTP Request Recursively on VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-resource

I've checked many places to do that.However, not found any solution about it. Let's suppose, we have got HTTP post request in any method. I am trying to call HTTP post request recursively. The issue is, when I tried to do it with setInterval function, there are some requests pending on queue due to connectivity issues. It's accumulating on the queue while the connection is low. What I want to do is, do not send a request before latest request sent. What is the best practice for it?

Comment: Is this what you need? https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/63t082p2/79/

Comment: Obviously, it is. Can you please type your solution as an answer. I can check mark of it. This is really useful solution that's why I am asking for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a function which returns [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), and another function, which resolves this Promise and calls itself again in `.then` callback:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    fetchCounter: 0 // used here to prevent infinite requests 
  },
  methods: {
    myFetch: function() {
      return fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1/')
    },
    loopFetch: function() {
      this.myFetch().then(res => {
       console.log(res.status, ' ', this.fetchCounter++);
        if (this.fetchCounter < 10) { // repeat 10 times, then abort
          setTimeout(this.loopFetch, 1000); // sort of debounce
        } else {
          console.log('aborted')
        }
      })
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.loopFetch(); // first call of the loopFetch function 
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```